# Continue to the next iteration

Tags: java, loops, do-while

I just want to know what is the problem that don't let my program to continue to the next iteration..
this is my code:

```
  public static void main(String []args){
    int height = 5;
    int width = 10;


    for(int i =0; i<height; i++){
        char[] ligne ;
        do{
        System.out.println("tapez la ligne " + i + ":");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        ligne = sc.next().toCharArray(); //



        } while(ligne.length != width);
    }
 }
```

The result is always: Tapez la ligne 0:

Thanks

Comment: And what do you enter? (for `sc.next()` I mean)

Comment: Have you tried inputting a string that has a length of 10? Or have you tried debugging to understand better on what your code is doing?

Comment: @LaroussiNader... If you enter a character your code will never break out of the do {} while()... you must enter a string of length 10 the way your code is written.

Comment: As you can see here `while(ligne.length != width)`, `a character` is not enough. Enter something like `0123456789`.

Answer (score 0):

You internal loop do{}while(cond) will exit if you enter a string which has 10 chars. do{}while(cond) will exit only if the inverse of the cond is found.